# Maximum length of content?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to connect with a server using `HttpURLConnection`, but I have a problem with the PUT method.
I need to send a String with *1500 characters* (or more), but in this case the server produces a timeout and returns **500 - server internal error**.
If I send a String lower than *1400 characters*, I have not problem and the server returns **OK**.

My code is the following:

```
public String connectToServer(String prototype) {
    String responseString = "";

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openURLForInput(new URL(URL), USERNAME, PASSWORD, prototype)));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            responseString += line;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseString = e.toString();
    }

    return responseString;
}
```

//-----------------------

```
public InputStream openURLForInput(URL url, String uname, String pword, String content) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", userNamePasswordBase64(uname, pword)); // I know this is OK
    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");

    //conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(8 * 1024);

    conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    conn.connect();

    OutputStream output = conn.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    writer.write(content); // content length  > 1400 characters
    writer.close();
    output.close();

    int status = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.i("STATUS", status + "");
    Log.i("STATUS_ERROR", conn.getResponseMessage());

    return conn.getInputStream();
}
```

I tryed adding the lines

```
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(contentLength)
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(8 * 1024);
```

But the server's answer is wrong anyway.

**UPDATE:**

I could detect the problem. For some reason, when I try to send large bodys in the request, the server produces a timeout **but not with all networks**, only with some networks. I use a secure conection  SSL, maybe this can bring problems?

Comment: And what kind of server is it you are connecting to; do you have admin access to it or is the admin a friendly guy at the table next to you?

Comment: try adding this: conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", content.getLength());

Comment: Class Stacker:We can, but what should we ask? that part i dont know.

@Kylar: We already tried that way and still getting the message cut to 1415 charcters. The strange thing is that we get a TimeOut when we send 1416, not the message with 1 missing character (is this clear?)

Comment: Can you get a wire level trace (using wireshark, tcpflow, or something else?)

Comment: We need more information to help you. Can you answer the following questions ? A -> What server is this ? (tomcat / JBoss) B -> Post the stack trace of the HTTP 500. It should be available in the application log or server log. C -> Is the 500 thrown by the code or the container ? D -> Post the HTTP Request and Response that results in the 500. E -> Post the server side code that processes the request.

Comment: A. Tomcat

B. Logcat exception: Error in http connection ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

C. I don't know. We can't access to that kind of information. What information we would get from it?

D. The http request is my code above

E. I can't access to the server's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's a network MTU problem, I'd say you investigate on that front.

Here's a table relevant to windows:

```
Network             MTU (bytes)
-------------------------------
16 Mbps Token Ring        17914
4 Mbps Token Ring          4464
FDDI                       4352
Ethernet                   1500
IEEE 802.3/802.2           1492
PPPoE (WAN Miniport)       1480
X.25                        576
```

Comment: Yes! Recently I just realized that that was the problem, thank you. Do you know how can I set the network MTU from the code?

Comment: No, you can't set that in code, since the MTU is a value set when whatever network interface you have goes up/enabled. What you CAN do is to try setting another network configuration for your ISP or network card (or router).

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, if you think in another solution please let me know  =)

Comment: I'm sure the MTU can't be changed in code. It's a network thing. Glad it helped sany

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to use the very helpful [**HTTP-REQUEST**](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) library by Kevin Sawicki...

It helped me a lot of times !

Comment: I tried with this but I got the same answer =( It is based in httpUrlConnection and we already tried that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The server is responding 500 - server internal error. So you should check the server implementation. It should have restrictions above that content length.
I have a app that do a lot of server http requests and for me your problem really is the server. The main evidence is that your code works with content lower or equals then 1415 chars.

Comment: They said the server doesn't have limitations

Comment: I tried in my cellphone(3g) and the app works fine, but when I connect using wifi through a global crossing connection the server returns "500 - server internal error", which means timeout. The WEIRD PART is that if I connect my cellphone using wifi, but another ISP (not Global Crossing), the connection works fine