# How to Upload large files using ChunkedStreaming in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, httpurlconnection

I need to post some large files to server. I am able to upload the files which are < 3 MB , but while i am uploading a file which is > 3 MB, it shows me the Internal server exception and server response code "500". Initially, I thought it is a server side issue but I can post the large file through iOS app(By using the same url), same way I need to implement it in android.

Here is my code --

```
public String postMediaDataToServer(String evidenceId, File file) {

            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundarysNDKBMUFqqvzYWGh";

            Date date = new Date();
            String timestamp = dateFormat.format(date);
            String fileName = file.getName();
            if (fileName.endsWith(".jpg") || fileName.endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                    fileName = "image_" + timestamp + ".jpg";
            } else if (fileName.endsWith(".wav")) {
                    fileName = "audio_" + timestamp + ".wav";
            } else if (fileName.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                    fileName = "video_" + timestamp + ".mp4";
            } else if (fileName.endsWith(".3gp")) {
                    fileName = "video_" + timestamp + ".3gp";
            }




            String response = "error";
        Log.e("Image filename", fileName);
        Log.e("url", ApplicationData.getBaseUrl()
                            + "Media");
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        // DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = fileName;
        String urlServer = ApplicationData.getBaseUrl()
                            + "Media";


        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1000*1024);
            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);


            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-Ecordia-Software", "ecordiApp");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="
                                    + boundary);

                    List<Cookie> cookies = ApplicationData.getCookieStore()
                                    .getCookies();
                    if (cookies.size() > 0)
                             connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies.get(0).getName() + "="
                                            + cookies.get(0).getValue());

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"EvidenceIdentifier\""
                                    + lineEnd + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(evidenceId + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    if (fileName.endsWith(".jpg") || fileName.endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File0\"; filename=\""
                                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd + lineEnd);
                    } else if (fileName.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File0\"; filename=\""
                                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: video/mp4" + lineEnd + lineEnd);

                    } else if (fileName.endsWith(".wav")) {
                            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File0\"; filename=\""
                                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: audio/wav" + lineEnd + lineEnd);
                    }
                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                                    + lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Log.e("Image length", bytesAvailable + "");
            try {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
                        return response;
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "error";
                return response;
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("Server Response Code ", "" + serverResponseCode);
            Log.i("Server Response Message", serverResponseMessage);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                response = "true";
            }


            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
            response = "error";
            Log.e("Send file Exception", ex.getMessage() + "");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It is better to put your code in your question rather than linking to it.

Comment: Check this out [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433844/maximum-length-of-content).  This seems to describe a similar problem.

Comment: A 500 **is** a server side issue. Please update your post with the entire content of the HTTP response.